# mongodb 2.6.1: adding index changes result set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I create a simple collection with

```
db.getCollection("types").insert({
  "domainId": "type",
});
db.getCollection("types").insert({
  "domainId": "view",
});
db.getCollection("types").insert({
  "domainId": "vfsdata",
  "namespace": "eportal",
});
db.getCollection("types").insert({
  "domainId": "admin",
  "namespace": "eportal",
});
```

As expected the following query return all documents:

```
> db.types.find( { "$or" : [ { "namespace" : "eportal"} , { "namespace" :  null }] } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c13"), "domainId" : "type" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c14"), "domainId" : "view" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c15"), "domainId" : "vfsdata", "namespace" : "eportal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c16"), "domainId" : "admin", "namespace" : "eportal" }
```

Now I add an index with

```
db.types.ensureIndex( { namespace: 1, domainId: 1 }, { unique: 1 } )
```

After this the same query as above returns only 2 documents:

```
> db.types.find( { "$or" : [ { "namespace" : "eportal"} , { "namespace" :  null }] } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c13"), "domainId" : "type" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("538602b59b6fe0b5efcf8c14"), "domainId" : "view" }
```

I have no explanation for this behavior. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

See the manual entry for [`sparse indexes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) with unique constraint. I think you'll want to do this:

```
db.types.ensureIndex(
  { namespace: 1, domainId: 1 },
  { unique: true, sparse: true }
)
```

Comment: With a sparse index I get the expected result. But in the manual I found:'Changed in version 2.6: If a sparse index results in an incomplete result set for queries and sort operations, MongoDB will not use that index'. So I think I get the correct result because MongoDB doesn't use the index.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Reading the docs more carefully, it seems you want explicitly sparse = false, but that's the default and doesn't work even if you hint. Oddly, if you use sparse = true, it does work (and does use the index) if you hint. That's rather... confusing.

Comment: And with version 2.4 everything work as expected. The query in my example returns 4 object even if I use the "normal" index. Could it be a bug in MongoDB version 2.6?

Comment: Looks like -- I don't see anything in the 2.6 changelog that indicates there was a change to this behavior.